# Invoke-Command InDisconnectedSession SessionOption and IdleTimeout One Liner

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to do the following simple one liner:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -Credential Administrator { ipconfig } -InDisconnectedSession -SessionOption @{ IdleTimeout = 180000 }
```

But get the following error:

```
Invoke-Command : The specified IdleTimeout session option 0 (seconds) is not
a valid period.  Specify an IdleTimeout value that is greater than or equal to
the minimum allowed 60 (seconds).
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -Credential Administrator { ip ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

Example 16 from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-5.1) appears to be very similar, but I couldn't get that to work as well.

Comment: are you running ps6+? those docs are not for ps5.1 ... [*grin*] also, what does this >>> `-Credential Administrator { ipconfig }` <<< do? i can't find any hint what you are attempting with that. [*blush*]

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Lee—I’m actually running 5.1, but the example is the same for both versions.  `-Credential Administrator` just prompts for the Administrator’s password (ultimately I’d like to use this command on remote computers) and `ipconfig` was an arbitrary choice—any command would still return the same error.

Comment: ah! the scriptblock is for the `-ScriptBlock` parameter. somehow i thot that went with the `-Credential` parameter. when you are having problems with code, you _really otta use parameter names_. [*grin*] ///// so ... **_what happens when you REMOVE the spaces in the session options hashtable?_**

Comment: Same issue Lee, but I appreciate your thoughts ;) .

Comment: arg! hopefully the code posted by `Ivan Mirchev` will do the job ... i am out of ideas. [*sigh ...*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -Credential Administrator -ScriptBlock { ipconfig } -InDisconnectedSession -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -IdleTimeout 180000)`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that all time values in a PSSessionOption object are [TimeSpan] types. You must specify the IdleTimeout value in ticks (ms * 1000) or use a conversion method of the TimeSpan class for the conversion from hashtable to work.

```
$parameters @{
  ComputerName='localhost'
  Credential='Administrator'
  ScriptBlock = { ipconfig } 
  InDisconnectedSession=$true
  SessionOption = @{ IdleTimeout = [TimeSpan]::FromSeconds(180) }
}
Invoke-Command @parameters
```